# Replace html element with another

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

This Meteor template helper gets its raw html from mongodb collection, it then needs to replace a specific `tr` element with a pre created tr element `myTr`. It would be nice to use javascript but the below is using jQuery which is not doing the job.
How can it be done? Thanks

```
Template.myHelper.helpers({
  info: function() {
    let myTr = document.createElement('tr');
    //do things in myTr.
    let data = myCollection.findOne({});
    let jObj = $($.parseHTML(data.rawHTML));
    jObj.find('td.myClass').each(function() {
      if (this.textContent === "found it") {
        this.parentElement.id = 'myId';
        jObj(this.parentElement).replaceWith(myTr); //<-- failed to repalce
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: @HappyCoding pre created `tr` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have beatifull mix of variables. Look

> `jObj(this.parentElement).replaceWith(myTr); //<-- failed to repalce`

```
jObj //that's jquery element
this //that's html element
this.parentElement //that's also html element

jObj(this.parentElement) //what's this? supposed to be jquery object
```

try changing `jObj(this.parentElement)` to `$(this.parentElement)` and it will work

Comment: How can it be made so that all in jQuery or JS and no mix?

Comment: I'd use jquery only, so no `this.parentElement` - put `$(this).parent()` instead. Not `this` but `$(this)`. Not `this.textContent` but `$(this).text()` and so on ...